# Как собрать Android восьмой версии под устройство на Android шестой версии?

Tags: android, build, ос

Есть смартфон на Android шестой версии. Процессор MediaTek (6797). Прошивка основана на старом ядре (3.18), которое, как я понял, невозможно обновить из-за отсутствия исходников.

Допустим, я хочу собрать Android восьмой версии под это устройство - есть ли такая возможность и, если да, то как?

В интернете что-то об этом пишут, но очень поверхностно - этой информации недостаточно, чтобы дать ответ на подобный вопрос.

Хочется получить развернутый ответ, если, конечно, это возможно.

*Видимо, старое ядро Linux: https://github.com/MT6797/kernel-3.18*